# Possible to convert HTML+CSS animation(png extension image) to .gif extension image?

Tags: html, css, animation, gif

I Need to create Loader GIF, but the loader is made with HTML + CSS animation(png extension image), and I want to convert the web loader to GIF image, Any tool available to convert HTML to GIF.

Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/6uedrb89/6/

Here's the demo:

Anyone please help me to solve this issue

Thanks in advance

```
<div class="tc-play-animated-loading">
    <img src="https://s27138.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/favIcon.png" alt="play" class="tc-play-animated">
</div>

<style>
div.tc-play-animated-loading {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50% );
}

img.tc-play-animated {
    -webkit-animation: play-filter-animation 8s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: play-filter-animation 8s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: play-filter-animation 8s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: play-filter-animation 8s linear infinite;
    animation: play-filter-animation 8s linear infinite; 
}
@-webkit-keyframes play-filter-animation{
    from{
        -webkit-filter:hue-rotate(-360deg)
    }
    to{
        -webkit-filter:hue-rotate(360deg)
    }
}
@-o-keyframes play-filter-animation{
    from{
        -o-filter:hue-rotate(-360deg)
    }
    to{
        -o-filter:hue-rotate(360deg)
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes play-filter-animation{
    from{
        -moz-filter:hue-rotate(-360deg)
    }
    to{
        -moz-filter:hue-rotate(360deg)
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes play-filter-animation{
    from{
        -ms-filter:hue-rotate(-360deg)
    }
    to{
        -ms-filter:hue-rotate(360deg)
    }
}
@keyframes play-filter-animation{
    0%{
        filter:hue-rotate(-360deg)
    }
    50%{
        filter:hue-rotate(360deg)
    }
    100%{
        filter:hue-rotate(0)
    }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Changes `filter:hue` to `transform`

```
@-webkit-keyframes play-filter-animation{
   0%{-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)}
   100%{-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)}
}

@keyframes play-filter-animation{

  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/u7fw4jd5/6/